# Does it matter if my 1099-INT lists an out-of-date home address?

Tags: united-states, taxes, irs, interest, form-1099

My 1099-INT lists an older address. I checked my bank account, and my address is up to date, but since I moved last year, I guess they kept the old address on the form.

My tax filing software lists my up-to-date address on the 1099-INT form and does not let me change it. Will it be an issue if the address listed on the 1099-INT form does not match the one that I submit via the tax filing software?

Do I need to contact the IRS or my bank letting them know about the discrepancy, or is it a non-issue?

Comment: It could be a problem if the old and new addresses are in different states with different tax rates, but I don't know enough about tax accounting to know further details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unlike the W-2, a 1099 is not included when you file with your 1040 personal income tax.  It is primarily for informational purposes - you use it to calculate other amounts.  A copy is also supplied to the IRS, so you do want to ensure that your social security number is correct.  Other than that, the address isn't really relevant - except as noted above that there could be issues with earnings in different taxing jurisdictions (different states may have different income tax rates, for instance, or it just may change your total in a given jurisdiction).

The address is rarely important on any of the forms (except regarding your actual address to send a refund) - you might move several times during a year or even between the first of the year and when you get your forms, or when you file.  You could also have different mailing addresses (a P.O. Box, a work address, etc.) that would appear, which would not necessarily reflect your home address at any point in time.

You should follow up with your bank anyway to ensure the correct information is carried through their system - they may have different mailing address and physical address entries and only one got updated.

Answer (score 4):

You should surely contact the bank that issued the form and get them to correct their records. They could issue a corrected form, but if the SSN/Tax ID no is correct, this is probably not essential.